# $f(x)=x+2x^2\sin(1/x)$ increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

The function is as follows.

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} x+2x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x}) &\text{, if $x\neq 0$}\\ 0 &\text{, otherwise} \end{cases}$$

i solved the problem as follows,

$f$ is not increasing for any neighborhood of $0$

By using the fact,
For $x_n={1\over2n\pi}$, 
$f'(x_n)=-1$ then f is not monotone increasing for any closed interval $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, thus the above statement holds.

Is it correct? If it is correct i have the 2 questions.

How to show that

1. $f(x)<0$ for any $x\in({-1\over2},0)$
2. $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in(0,{1\over2})$

I solved the for any $n\in N$, $f(x_n)<f(y_n)$ where $x_n={1 \over 2n\pi}$ and $y_n={1 \over (2n+{1 \over 2})\pi}$.

How can i solve it?

Comment: For showing yours inequality use $|sin(x)|<x$ true for all $x$.

Comment: @EDX $|\sin x| < x$ is clearly wrong for $x<0$....I think you meant $|\frac{\sin x}{x}|<1$

Comment: @SaketGurjar **EDX** statement is correct. See this [link](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proof-that-sin-x-x-for-all-positive-real-numbers)

Comment: @Mrcrg The link talks about : $\sin x < x$....which I do agree on.....but in $|\sin x|<x$ for a negative number : $|\sin{(-'ve)}|<(-'ve) \to (+'ve) < (-'ve)$.....that's what I pointed out....the use of modulus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that $-1\le \sin(1/x)\le 1$.  So, we have

$$x-2x^2\le x+2x^2\sin(1/x)$$

and $x-2x^2>0$ when $0<x<1/2$.  Can you finish the argument?

Comment: No... i can't understand, how to show that?

Comment: @Crawl I've edited to make things clearer.